# Un aggettivo in prestito dal francese va declinato secondo il genere?

Tags: gender, foreign-words

Tutti conosciamo la regola per cui i prestiti da lingue straniere non si declinano secondo il numero, per esempio:

> Mi piacciono i *film* di Fellini.

Vale anche per il genere di un aggettivo (in particolare, in francese)?

> Ma che gonna *démodée*, è di tua nonna?
>
> Sei simpatica quando sei così *tranchante*, ma è un vestito tuo.
>
> *Touchée*!

In ciascuno di questi tre esempi ho aggiunto una E secondo le regole del francese, perché i tre aggettivi si riferiscono a sostantivi di genere femminile.

Comment: Altro esempio (con possibile soluzione): [Naif](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/naif/)

Comment: [Démodé](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/demode/) (occhio al primo accento) sembra declinabile, forse si fa con quelli semplici e non con "naif" :)

Comment: Grazie, correggo.

Comment: Le parole straniere in italiano non si declinano.

Comment: Purtroppo non è così semplice, come viene fuori anche dall'altra risposta e dai commenti.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La morfologia della lingua di partenza di un prestito non adattato è di solito «invisibile» alla lingua d’arrivo, qualora il prestito sia acclimato, e non si tratti quindi di una citazione.

Lo stesso dovrebbe valere anche gli aggettivi. Tuttavia, i dizionari riportano esempi non concordi. Ecco il *Treccani* alla voce «[démodé](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/demode/)»:

> Fuori moda, passato di moda: *un cappellino d.*, *una camicetta d.*;
>   fig., di cosa antiquata, desueta: *teorie ormai démodées*.

La declinazione secondo la lingua di partenza è rispettata solo per un esempio, si può dire, «colto», nel quale il francesismo ha piú l’aspetto di una citazione che di un prestito. Infatti, il *Treccani* non riporta l’aggettivo per esteso per «una camicetta démodé», sottintendendo che, in quel caso, l’aggettivo rimane invariato nel genere e non diventa *démodée*.

Il *De Mauro* invece è meno ambiguo:

> [**demodé**](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/demode)
>
> /demo'de*/ dé|mo|dé agg.inv.

Indica come invariabile anche *tranchant*:

> [**tranchant**](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/tranchant)
>
> tran|chant agg.inv.

La scelta dipende da come si considera quell’aggettivo: citazione prestigiosa oppure parola straniera di uso comune.

Comment: +1. Proprio la risposta che volevo scrivere io. :)

Comment: Direi che anche per il genere si verifichi qualcosa di simile a quello che scrive Serianni (p. 563 di *Italiano*, ed. Garzanti) a proposito del numero: [segue]

Comment: «...i non molti francesismi ancora in circolazione presuppongono in chi li adopera una certa cultura (proprio perché si tratta in gran parte di termini astratti, scelti non per necessità ma per il loro prestigio): quindi *le débâcles* (con gli accenti al posto giusto e la *s* del plurale; diversamente, non mancano termini italiani come *disfatta*, *sconfitta*, *disastro*, *sfacelo*), *gli escamotages* (o *escamotaggi*, *espedienti*, *trovate*, *giochi di bussolotti*), *le querelles* ...». E aggiungo “le *fiches*” in cui il plurale (e il corsivo) si conserva anche per evitare malintesi.

Comment: @DaG Ho scritto un libro contro il gioco d'azzardo e ho proprio dovuto fare come dici per parlare di _fiches_...

Answer (score 0):

Sono usate tutte e due le varianti. Un tempo il francese era la seconda lingua dei "salotti buoni", e parole di questo tipo erano usate anche per darsi un tono. Oggi mi aspetto di vedere queste parole usate soprattutto da persone che vogliono sfoggiare una cultura un po' *démodé*, e sempre per lo stesso motivo di leggerle nella forma declinata più spesso che il contrario.